# Integrate PGP encryption in FTP command

Tags: linux, ftp, pgp

I am a Linux user. I need to upload some files to a second server. This one uses PGP as security and I received a PGP key. Am I wrong when I say that I cannot use the ordinary FTP client program with a PGP key and that I need another tool like [this one](http://www.pgpi.org/)?
Is there a way to integrate this PGP key I've been given with my Linux `ftp` command?

Answer (score 1):

I think they are looking for you to encrypt your files with the key that was provided.  FTP is an insecure protocol.  Based on what you have provided that would be the logical answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Grim76's assessment -- it sounds like you're expected to PGP-encrypt any files prior to uploading them via ftp.

Using gpg (it is almost certainly installed on your linux machine) for this, here's what it would look like:

```
gpg import TheirPGPkey.asc
gpg -k
gpg -er TheirID InputFile
```

For the `TheirID` part, inspect the `gpg -k` output and use their email address, name, or keyid (the number to the left of the date). Running the above should generate a file with the same name -- with a `.gpg` extension added to the end.

Comment: He made it sound like they were using GPG for authentication...like to even login.